# O que é programação dinâmica?

Tags: algoritmo, ciência-da-computação

O que é programação dinâmica ?

> Programação dinâmica **NÃO** é tipagem dinâmica

- Quais suas características ?
- Quais suas vantagens e desvantagens ?

Comment: Para não ficar muito extenso, recomendo que você quebre suas perguntas em mais de uma página.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Quando você começa a trabalhar com mais de um sistema, pode correr uma série de conflitos devido ao uso de algoritmos recursivos, que reexaminam o mesmo problema muitas vezes, e nesta situação, gerando novos conflitos e bugs.

Para resolver esses problemas, existe a **programação dinâmica**, que se trata de uma metodologia de construção de algoritmos que resolvam  problemas originais do sistema, de forma que otimize e faça uso da análise combinatória, afim de prevenir queda de performance e recálculos desnecessários para atender subsistemas que possam sobrepujar o sistema original, gerando novos subproblemas.

Ou seja, quando você começar a programar, o ideal é você pensar em abstrair o máximo que puder para que não ocorra problemas no futuro, isso é um pensamento dinâmico.

Answer (score 13):

"Muitos algoritmos eficientes seguem o paradigma da programação dinâmica.  Esse paradigma, ou estratégia de projeto de algoritmos, é uma espécie de tradução iterativa inteligente da recursão e pode ser definido, vagamente, como recursão com apoio de uma tabela.

Como em um algoritmo recursivo, cada instância do problema é resolvida a partir da solução de instâncias menores, ou melhor, de subinstâncias da instância original.  A característica distintiva da programação dinâmica é a tabela que armazena as soluções das várias subinstâncias.  O consumo de tempo do algoritmo é, em geral, proporcional ao tamanho da tabela."

Fonte: http://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/analise_de_algoritmos/aulas/dynamic-programming.html

Answer (score 4):

Um problema conhecido e simples que é comumente usado para demonstrar programação dinâmica é o cálculo recursivo dos números de Fibonacci.

Em **Lua** este cálculo é feito assim:

```
function fib(n)
  if n == 0 then
    return 1
  elseif n == 1 then
    return 1
  else
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
  end
end

for n = 1, 10 do
  io.write(fib(n), ", ")
end
io.write("...\n")
```

Uma versão deste programa mostrando as chamadas recursivas feitas:

```
local newline = false
local N = arg[1] or 5

function print_level(lev)
  if newline then
    io.write(string.rep(" ", 9*lev))
    newline = false
  end
end

function fib(n, level)

  if n == 0 then
    print_level(level)
    io.write(" --> f(0)\n")
    newline = true
    return 1

  elseif n == 1 then
    print_level(level)
    io.write(" --> f(1)\n")
    newline = true
    return 1

  else
    print_level(level)
    io.write(" --> f(" .. n .. ")")
    return fib(n-1, level+1) + fib(n-2, level+1)
  end
end

print "----------------------------"
print(" calculando fib(" .. N .. ")")
local f = fib(tonumber(N), 0)
print(" fib(" .. N .. ")=" .. f)
print "----------------------------"
```

Cálculo de fib(0) até fib(5)

```
$ lua fib.lua 0                                  
----------------------------                     
 calculando fib(0)                               
 --> f(0)                                        
 fib(0)=1                                        
----------------------------                     

$ lua fib.lua 1                                  
----------------------------                     
 calculando fib(1)                               
 --> f(1)                                        
 fib(1)=1                                        
----------------------------                     

$ lua fib.lua 2                                  
----------------------------                     
 calculando fib(2)                               
 --> f(2) --> f(1)                               
          --> f(0)                               
 fib(2)=2                                        
----------------------------                     

$ lua fib.lua 3                                  
----------------------------                     
 calculando fib(3)                               
 --> f(3) --> f(2) --> f(1)                      
                   --> f(0)                      
          --> f(1)                               
 fib(3)=3                                        
----------------------------                     

$ lua fib.lua 4                                  
----------------------------                     
 calculando fib(4)                               
 --> f(4) --> f(3) --> f(2) --> f(1)             
                            --> f(0)             
                   --> f(1)                      
          --> f(2) --> f(1)                      
                   --> f(0)                      
 fib(4)=5                                        
----------------------------                     

 $ lua fib.lua 5
 ----------------------------                         
 calculando fib(5)                                   
 --> f(5) --> f(4) --> f(3) --> f(2) --> f(1)        
                                     --> f(0)        
                            --> f(1)                 
                   --> f(2) --> f(1)                 
                            --> f(0)                 
          --> f(3) --> f(2) --> f(1)                 
                            --> f(0)                 
                   --> f(1)                          
 fib(5)=8                                            
----------------------------
```

O que se vê é são feitos muitos cálculos repetidos.
Para fib(10), por exemplo, fib(0) é calculado 34 vezes, e fib(1) é calculado 55 vezes.

Uma maneira de evitar esses cálculos repetidos é guardar em um mapa em memória (dicionário, hash, etc, dependendo da linguagem) um valor que é calculado da primeira vez. Das outras vezes basta consultar o mapa em memória, e se o valor já foi calculado então não precisa ser calculado novamente.

Programa acima utilizando este método de cálculo:

```
local newline = false
local N = arg[1] or 5

local cache = {}

function print_level(lev)
  if newline then
    io.write(string.rep(" ", 9*lev))
    newline = false
  end
end

function fib(n, level)

  if n == 0 then
    print_level(level)
    io.write(" --> f(0)\n")
    newline = true
    return 1

  elseif n == 1 then
    print_level(level)
    io.write(" --> f(1)\n")
    newline = true
    return 1

  else
    print_level(level)
    io.write(" --> f(" .. n .. ")")
    local saved = cache[n]
    if saved then
      io.write("\n")
      newline = true
      return saved
    else
      saved = fib(n-1, level+1) + fib(n-2, level+1)
      cache[n] = saved
      return saved
    end
  end
end

print "----------------------------"
print(" calculando fib(" .. N .. ")")
local f = fib(tonumber(N), 0)
io.write("\n")
print(" fib(" .. N .. ")=" .. f)
print "----------------------------"
```

Nesta versão, ao se calcular fib(10), fib(0) é calculado apenas 1 vez, e fib(1) é calculado 2 vezes!

Para se verificar estes números, usar os seguintes comandos:

```
$ fib_v1(10) | grep -c "f(0)"
$ fib_v1(10) | grep -c "f(1)"
```

e

```
$ fib_v2(10) | grep -c "f(0)"
$ fib_v2(10) | grep -c "f(1)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Programação dinâmica é um paradigma aplicado a problemas complexos de computação, uma metodologia de construção de algoritmos que resolvam problemas originais do sistema, de forma que otimize e faça uso da análise combinatória, afim de prevenir queda de performance e recálculos desnecessários. Podemos associar a ela recursos como recursividade de um código.

Quanto as vantagens:

- A implementação garante a praticidade quando aplicada a código que exigem testes com todas possibilidades.
- A precisão numérica não é importante.

DESVANTAGENS:

- Consome muito memória pra o processamento.
- Dependendo do problema, a complexidade espacial do mesmo pode vir a ser gigantesca.