# O que é um Algoritmo Guloso?

Tags: algoritmo, ciência-da-computação

O que é um Algoritmo **Guloso** ?

- Quais suas características ?
- Quais suas vantagens e desvantagens ?

Comment: Qual o motivo do negativo?

Comment: eu respondo: "Bem-vindo ao stackoverlow em português"

Comment: Não fui eu. +1, também quero saber o que é o algorítimo guloso.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Algoritmo **Guloso** é uma solução comum para problemas de otimização onde:

- Realiza a escolha que parece ser a melhor no momento na esperança de que
  a mesma acarrete em uma solução ou prevenção de futuros problemas a
  nível global.
- É simples e de fácil implementação;
- É míope: ele toma decisões com base nas informações disponíveis na
  iteração corrente.

**Características**

- Jamais se arrepende de uma decisão, as escolhas realizadas são definitivas;
- Não leva em consideração as consequências de suas decisões;
- Podem fazer cálculos repetitivos;
- Nem sempre produz a melhor solução (depende da quantidade de
  informação fornecida);
- Quanto mais informações, maior a chance de produzir uma solução melhor.

**Algoritmos Gulosos vs [Programação Dinâmica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102816/o-que-%C3%A9-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-din%C3%A2mica?rq=1)**

- Em um algoritmo de programação dinâmica a escolha pode depender da solução
  dos subproblemas, enquanto um algoritmo guloso vai tentar escolher a melhor
  solução naquele momento.
- A solução dos problemas na programação dinâmica parte de baixo para cima,
  enquanto um algoritmo guloso vai de cima para baixo, ou seja, na programação
  dinâmica, as soluções para todos os subproblemas são calculadas partindo dos
  menores subproblemas para os maiores.
- Os resultados dos subproblemas na programação dinâmica são salvos, facilitando a prova de correção.

**Pontos a favor**

- Simples e de fácil implementação;
- Algoritmos de rápida execução;
- Podem fornecer a melhor solução (estado ideal).

**Pontos Contra**

- Dependentes de informações;
- Correm o risco de entrarem em loops infinitos;
- Situacionais, só resolvem tipos específicos de problemas;
- Decisões tomadas são irrevogáveis;

**Código de exemplo** (neste caso uma implementação simples de uma devolução de troco gulosa)

```java
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Troco {

    public String calculaTroco(double conta, double pago) {
        DecimalFormat formatador = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00");
        if (pago < conta)
            return ("\nPagamento insuficiente, faltam R$" + formatador.format(conta - pago) + "\n");
        else {

            String resultado;
            double troco;

            troco = pago - conta;
            resultado = "\nTroco = R$" + formatador.format(troco) + "\n\n";

            resultado = this.calculaNotas(troco, resultado);
            resultado = this.calculaMoedas(troco, resultado);

            resultado = resultado + "\n";

            return (resultado);
        }
    }

    private String calculaNotas(final double troco, String resultado) {

        int nota[] = { 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1 };

        int valor;
        int ct;

        int contadorNota = 0;

        valor = (int) troco;
        while (valor != 0) {
            ct = valor / nota[contadorNota]; // calculando a qtde de notas
            if (ct != 0) {
                resultado = resultado + (ct + " nota(s) de R$" + nota[contadorNota] + "\n");
                valor = valor % nota[contadorNota]; // sobra
            }
            contadorNota++; // próxima nota
        }
        return resultado;
    }

    private String calculaMoedas(final double troco, String resultado) {

        int centavos[] = { 50, 25, 10, 5, 1 };

        int contadorMoeda = 0;
        int valor;
        int ct;

        valor = (int) Math.round((troco - (int) troco) * 100);
        while (valor != 0) {
            ct = valor / centavos[contadorMoeda]; // calculando a qtde de moedas
            if (ct != 0) {
                resultado = resultado + (ct + " moeda(s) de" + centavos[contadorMoeda] + "centavo(s)\n");
                valor = valor % centavos[contadorMoeda]; // sobra
            }
            contadorMoeda++; // próximo centavo
        }
        return resultado;
    }

}
```

Comment: Só para aprofundar, a solução do troco gulosa para este caso é ótima. Quando duas "moedas consecutivas" `m[i]` e `m_[i+1]` sempre satisfazem `2*m_[i] <= m_[i+1]` então a solução gulosa sempre será ótima