# Alguém pode me ajudar no problema de algoritmo guloso (Greedy algorithm)?

Tags: c

O problema pede para fazer o seguinte: Cortar um bastão de aço de comprimento n para se obter a máxima receita possível( Rod Cutting). Apresentar em algoritmo com backtraking(já fiz) e achar uma solução com algoritmo guloso.

Código do algoritmo feito usando Backtraking:

```
int max(int a, int b) { return (a > b)? a : b;}

int cutRod(int price[], int n)
{
   if (n <= 0)
     return 0;
   int max_val = INT_MIN;

   for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        max_val = max(max_val, price[i] + cutRod(price, n-i-1));

   return max_val;
}
```

Para fazer o código usando algoritmo guloso é necessário ordenar o vetor?

Comment: Bem vindo ao sopt. Formate o código, selecionando-o e clicando em `{}`

Comment: Algoritmo Guloso? Essa é nova pra mim....

Comment: Se eu pegar as partições com os maiores valores somando-as e ignorar as outras partições, isso seria considerado algoritmo guloso???

Comment: Poderia mandar o código completo? Com um exemplo do vetor de preferencia

Comment: Relacionado: [O que é um Algoritmo Guloso?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103681/3117)