# Recursividade em Java - MDC

Tags: java, recursão

Como posso implementar um contador no código abaixo para poder saber quantas chamadas recursivas vão acontecer para calcular o MDC de 14 e 18?

```
package Aula01;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Exer01 {

    public static double mdc(double dividendo, double divisor) {
        if ((dividendo % divisor == 0)) {
            return divisor;
        } else {
            return mdc(divisor, (dividendo % divisor));
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double n1;
        double n2;
        double resp;

        n1 = Double
                .parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite o primeiro número ou -1 para sair do programa"));
        n2 = Double
                .parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite o segundo número ou -1 para sair do programa"));

        while (n1 != -1 || n2 != -1) {
            resp = mdc(n1, n2);
            String result = String.format("%.0f", resp);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O resultado do MDC é: " + result);
            System.exit(0);

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro, acho que você devia ler o `n1` e `n2` dentro do `while`, senão não faz muito sentido você perguntar para o usuário isso e o `while` acabaria sendo equivalente a um `if`.

Segundo, que usar `System.exit(0)` não é boa prática de programação. Evite usar isso.

Terceiro, que o `mdc` é uma operação que só faz sentido com números inteiros, logo é estranho usar `double` para isso.

Quarto, nomes de pacotes deveriam ser sempre em letras minúsculas, e portanto `Aula01` seria chamado de `aula01`.

Quinto, que não é boa prática comer letras do nome das variáveis, e portanto `Exercicio01` seria melhor que `Exer01`.

Mas, agora focando-se na sua dúvida, há várias formas de se fazer isso. Listo 5 dessas formas abaixo:

- Variável estática - É considerada a alternativa mais simples. Mas não funciona quando você tiver múltiplas threads.

  ```
  package aula01;

  import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

  public class Exercicio01 {

      private static int contador = 0;

      public static int mdc(int dividendo, int divisor) {
          contador++;
          if (dividendo % divisor == 0) {
              return divisor;
          }
          return mdc(divisor, dividendo % divisor);
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          while (true) {
              int n1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                      "Digite o primeiro número ou -1 para sair do programa."));
              int n2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                      "Digite o segundo número ou -1 para sair do programa."));
              if (n1 == -1 || n2 == -1) break;

              contador = 0;
              int resposta = mdc(n1, n2);
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                      "O resultado do MDC é: " + resposta +
                      "\n Ocorreram " + contador + " recursões.");
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Variável thread-local - Semelhante à opção acima, mas um pouco mais complicada, funciona quando houver múltiplas threads.

  ```
  package aula01;

  import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

  public class Exercicio01 {

      private static final ThreadLocal<Integer> CONTADOR = new ThreadLocal<>();

      public static int mdc(int dividendo, int divisor) {
          CONTADOR.set(CONTADOR.get() + 1);
          if (dividendo % divisor == 0) {
              return divisor;
          }
          return mdc(divisor, dividendo % divisor);
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          while (true) {
              int n1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                      "Digite o primeiro número ou -1 para sair do programa."));
              int n2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                      "Digite o segundo número ou -1 para sair do programa."));
              if (n1 == -1 || n2 == -1) break;

              CONTADOR.set(0);
              int resposta = mdc(n1, n2);
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                      "O resultado do MDC é: " + resposta +
                      "\n Ocorreram " + CONTADOR.get() + " recursões.");
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Criar uma classe para representar a saída da função contendo também dados da recursão - Tende a complicar bastante o uso da função.

  ```
  package aula01;

  import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

  public class Exercicio01 {

      public static final class ResultadoMdc {
          private final int valor;
          private final int recursoes;

          public ResultadoMdc(int valor, int recursoes) {
              this.valor = valor;
              this.recursoes = recursoes;
          }

          public int getValor() {
              return valor;
          }

          public int getRecursoes() {
              return recursoes;
          }
      }

      private static ResultadoMdc mdc(int dividendo, int divisor, int recursoes) {
          if (dividendo % divisor == 0) {
              return new ResultadoMdc(divisor, recursoes);
          }
          return mdc(divisor, dividendo % divisor, recursoes + 1);
      }

      public static ResultadoMdc mdc(int dividendo, int divisor) {
          return mdc(dividendo, divisor, 0);
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          while (true) {
              int n1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                      "Digite o primeiro número ou -1 para sair do programa."));
              int n2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                      "Digite o segundo número ou -1 para sair do programa."));
              if (n1 == -1 || n2 == -1) break;

              ResultadoMdc resposta = mdc(n1, n2);
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                      "O resultado do MDC é: " + resposta.getValor() +
                      "\n Ocorreram " + resposta.getRecursoes() + " recursões.");
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Passar um parâmetro adicional à função que represente um contador - Complica a assinatura do método. Há duas formas de se fazer isso. Uma é usando `int[]` e a outra é usando `AtomicInteger`.

  Com `int[]`:

  ```
  package aula01;

  import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

  public class Exercicio01 {

      public static int mdc(int dividendo, int divisor, int[] contador) {
          contador[0]++;
          if (dividendo % divisor == 0) {
              return divisor;
          }
          return mdc(divisor, dividendo % divisor, contador);
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          while (true) {
              int n1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                      "Digite o primeiro número ou -1 para sair do programa."));
              int n2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                      "Digite o segundo número ou -1 para sair do programa."));
              if (n1 == -1 || n2 == -1) break;

              int[] contador = {0};
              int resposta = mdc(n1, n2, contador);
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                      "O resultado do MDC é: " + resposta +
                      "\n Ocorreram " + contador[0] + " recursões.");
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  Com `AtomicInteger`:

  ```
  package aula01;

  import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
  import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

  public class Exercicio01 {

      public static int mdc(int dividendo, int divisor, AtomicInteger contador) {
          contador.increment();
          if (dividendo % divisor == 0) {
              return divisor;
          }
          return mdc(divisor, dividendo % divisor, contador);
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          while (true) {
              int n1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                      "Digite o primeiro número ou -1 para sair do programa."));
              int n2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                      "Digite o segundo número ou -1 para sair do programa."));
              if (n1 == -1 || n2 == -1) break;

              AtomicInteger contador = new AtomicInteger(0);
              int resposta = mdc(n1, n2, contador);
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                      "O resultado do MDC é: " + resposta +
                      "\n Ocorreram " + contador.get() + " recursões.");
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Comer letras? Vai que é um [algoritmo guloso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103681/64969)

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Tem muita gente por aí que conheço que é bastante guloso quanto a nomes de variáveis, mas não quanto a boas práticas.

Comment: Eu sou novata em Java, você me deu uma super aula e me esclareceu muita coisa! Muito obrigada mesmo! Só tenho uma dúvida ainda: como substituir o system.out(0)? @VictorStafusa

Comment: @AnaBeatrizAraujo No lugar de `System.exit(0)` você normalmente usa `break` ou `return`. Em alguns casos, pode-se lançar uma exceção.

Comment: E porque o System.exit(0) não é uma boa prática em programação? @VictorStafusa (vou te interrogar mesmo, desculpa kkk tô com muita dúvidas nessa lista de exercícios)

Comment: @AnaBeatrizAraujo Porque o `System.exit(0)` é o botão para fazer com que o mundo acabe em um piscar de olhos. Ele não te pergunta se você tem certeza, não deixa salvar os arquivos abertos, não se interessa em saber quantos processos teriam que ser ordeiramente cancelados, e nem te dá qualquer satisfação sobre o que aconteceu. Nada disso, o resultado é apenas uma morte súbita e instantânea. [continua...]

Comment: [continuação...] Num projetinho simples como o seu, ele não é problemático, mas em projetos grandes, onde você tem centenas de classes fazendo um monte de coisas ao mesmo tempo, basta enfiar um `System.exit(0)` lá no meio para você ter todos os tipos de *bug reports*, usuários xingando e programadores fazendo caça-às-bruxas entre si. Trabalho com Java desde 2003 e até hoje **nunca** vi um único lugar sequer onde o `System.exit(0)` fosse algo bom de se fazer ou ao menos melhor que qualquer alternativa a ele.

Comment: Gente, não ensinam isso em faculdade não haha! Entendi agora, muito obrigada! <3 @VictorStafusa