# Diferença entre Divide and Conquer, Decrease and Conquer e Dynamic programming

Tags: algoritmo, dynamic

- Qual a diferença entre as técnicas de design de algoritmo `Divide and Conquer` e `Decrease and Conquer`?
- A `divide` é recursiva e a `decrease` não?
- Algum exemplo para a `decrease`?
- E `dynamic programming`?

Answer (score 0):

Olá! Primeiro é importante observar que todas essas técnicas são baseadas em indução.

`Divide and conquer` é uma técnica de projeto de algoritmos que consiste em dividir o problema em subproblemas menores. Esses algoritmos são divididos em duas fases: `divisão` e `conquista`. Na `divisão`, dividimos o problema ao meio (ou em alguma fração) e resolvemos cada subproblema. Na fase de `conquista`, combinamos as soluções dos subproblemas para obter a solução para o problema total. Exemplos de algoritmos que usam essa técnica são o `MergeSort` e o `QuickSort`.

`Decrease and conquer` é semelhante à `divide and conquer`, com a diferença de que nessa técnica a fase de `decrease` apenas diminui o problema, gerando um subproblema menor (ao invés de dividir em vários subproblemas). Após resolver o subproblema menor, a fase de `conquista` é executada para utilizar a solução do subproblema para obter a solução do problema total. Exemplos de algoritmos de `decrease and conquer` são `Busca Binária` (dividimos o vetor no meio e executamos a busca apenas em um dos lados) e `DFS`. Algoritmos de `decrease and conquer` também podem ser recursivos, a exemplo da busca binária.

Já a programação dinâmica é uma técnica que utiliza memorização para resolver subproblemas. Essa técnica faz sentido quando subproblemas se repetem. Um exemplo de problema que pode ser resolvido com programação dinâmica é o `fibonacci`, pois,  `fibonacci(N) = fibonacci(N-1) + fibonacci(N-2)`, `fibonacci(N-1) = fibonacci(N-2) + fibonacci(N-3)`, e assim por diante... Note que o subproblema `fibonacci(N-2)` se repete. A programação dinâmica consiste em memorizar as solução dos subproblemas para que não sejam recalculados.
Outra coisa importante é que a programação dinâmica só pode ser aplicada a problemas com subestrutura ótima. Dizer que um problema tem subestrutura ótima significa que uma solução ótima para o problema maior contém as soluções ótimas para os subproblemas.

Estou deixando algumas referências com explicações mais detalhadas.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/decrease-and-conquer/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13538459/difference-between-divide-and-conquer-algo-and-dynamic-programming
https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_din%C3%A2mica

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/371779/54255) tem uma resposta minha mostrando cálculo de números de fibonacci com memorização